# How to make ListView view auto scroll on top if EditText Grow

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-edittext

This is my problem.i have EditText and ListView if I have many text in EditText. ListView doesn't scroll on top so the result is ListView is now occupied by editText.

[This is the image when there is now text in EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buiSy.jpg)

[This is the image when there is now many texts in EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvWz2.jpg)

I hope someone understands and help me with this another problem

This is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:text="send"
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
    android:background="#EBEBEB"
    android:hint="Type your message here..."
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"/>


    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/messages_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"></ListView>
        
        
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wait I cannot see my image I posted here.... I hope you see it guys

Comment: Add in your full layout code for this. It seems that your editext and recyclerview are overlapping

Comment: Bro see my full layout code I have now edited it.and I don't use recycleview I use listView

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with my code and try. You will get your expected outcome

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainEditText"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_send"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type your message here..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot open it bro I think the layout is wrong... Bro help me with this plss.im stuck with this problem and I'm also a beginner

Comment: What you cannot open?

Comment: The code which I provided you the running code. I tested it myself